# Why is my fstream giving me the last output twice?

Tags: c++, class, fstream

I'm making this class called filestream, it's supposed to spit out a (txt) file like a stream.
I'm done but the thing is that the last entry is given twice.
What am I doing wrong here?

filestream.h:

```
class filestream {

public:
    std::string file_location;
    std::string get();
    explicit filestream(std::string file_location);
    bool at_end();
private:
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string s;
    std::fstream f;

};
```

filestream.cpp:

```
filestream::filestream(std::string file_location) : file_location(file_location) {
    f.open(file_location);
}

std::string filestream::get() {
    if (f.is_open()) {
        f >> s;
        return s;
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

bool filestream::at_end() {
    return f.eof();
}
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "demonic.h"

int main (){

    filestream fs("/home/devilish/Desktop/fruit.txt");
    while (!fs.at_end()){
        std::cout << fs.get() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Apple
Peer
Cherry
Mango
Mango
```

I tried this class twice but the results are the same, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I would say the single commonest misunderstanding we get here. `eof()` doesn't do what you think it does. Specifically it doesn't test if you are at the end of the file. Read the duplicate carefully.

Comment: PS  `return nullptr;` is incorrect. It's not legal to initialise a `std::string` with `nullptr`, this is likely to crash your program.

Comment: In addition, end of file is only one of many things that can go wrong when reading from a stream.. To be completely safe you should check ALL of them, and checking the stream state will report everything except validity of the actual data (if the data is garbage, you're gonna read garbage) .

Comment: Oke, I did not know that, so next question. How am I supposed to do it then?

Comment: I seem to have inadvertently given the C answer as the duplicate. I'll reopen and reclose with the C++ version.

Comment: @Demonic-Coder You'll have to reorganise your class, but `while (f >> s) { ... }` is the usual way.

Comment: This is the correct duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons Seems I'm no longer able to close having done it once already.

Comment: Thanks but, what about my at_end function now? How am I solving that?

Comment: Why do you need this function? You should check if the read was successful after you read from the file.

Comment: I'll think of something but thanks, I learned today.